# Which part of my name (Indian) is my surname?

Tags: indian-english, names

My name is *Abhijith S. Raj*.

So is my surname ***S. Raj*** or just ***Raj***?
(Note that my father's name is *Sreeraj* and that is why the *S. Raj*.)

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Indian name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_name) suggests that the use of surnames, patronymics, caste designations and toponyms, and their representation as initials, varies from one region or culture to another. If this is the case, I don't think this is a matter we can take up at all: it is a question of Indian practice which the English language does not address.

Comment: @StoneyB I wan't to register on collegeboard. They do not allow full stops in their text box. So i don't know how i will type S. Raj. I am anxious as it has to be the same name as on the test paper to receive results

Comment: Unhappily, there is no "rule" in the language for situations like this. My **guess** is that you should write your name as you always do, but omitting the full stop: **ABHIJITH S RAJ**. It is very common for official forms to ask for your 'middle initial'. But that is only a guess. Ultimately this is a question which only the people who designed the form can answer.

Comment: I would describe whichever form - either "Raj" or "S. Raj" that is consistently passed down in your family from generation to generation as the surname. That being said, I will note that insofar as college applications go - including for Collegeboard materials - the exact form you choose to use (that is, "Raj" or "S. Raj") is not terribly important: what matters the *most* is that your application can be traced back to *you*. Thus, as long as you consistently use the exact same form of your name (as long as it's reasonable) across all application materials, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is you father's name '****** S Raj' ? In that case, your surname would be 'S Raj'. However, when a person refers you, he wouldn't call you *'Mr. S Raj'* right ? He would just call you **'Mr. Raj'**. I'm an Indian and I too have the same problem. But I retained only my last name as my surname to fill out forms and I often get referred as just 'Mr. Nair' on my emails. So to avoid any confusion, you should use your surname as **Raj**.